# Override a controller Symfony 3.4/4.0

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm currently trying to override a controller from FOSUserBundle.
 In the new documentation,
(https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/override.html), they said we just have to override the route name of the bundle.

I've tried something like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Bundles;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController {
    /**
     * @Route("/registration/", name="fos_user_registration_register")
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request) {
    // My code
    }
```

But it does not work when I am rendering the FOS register form :

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register')) }}
```

This was working with Sf3.3 :(

Answer (score 9):

My solution - works fine from Symfony 4.1 by decorate FOS controller service.
Firstly - decorate selected controller (docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)
inside

```
App\Controller\ResettingController:
   decorates: fos_user.resetting.controller
   arguments:
   - '@App\Controller\ResettingController.inner'
   - '@event_dispatcher'
   - '@fos_user.resetting.form.factory'
   - '@fos_user.user_manager'
   - '@fos_user.util.token_generator'
   - '@fos_user.mailer'
   - '%fos_user.resetting.retry_ttl%'
   - '@security.csrf.token_manager'
```

Now controller which will override original ResettingController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController as BaseResettingController;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;


class ResettingController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var BaseResettingController
     */
    private $resettingController;

    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * @var FactoryInterface
     */
    private $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    /**
     * @var TokenGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $tokenGenerator;

    /**
     * @var MailerInterface
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $retryTtl;

    /**
     * @var CsrfTokenManagerInterface
     */
    private $csrfTokenManager;

    /**
     * ResettingController constructor.
     *
     * @param BaseResettingController $resettingController
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
     * @param FactoryInterface $formFactory
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     * @param TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator
     * @param MailerInterface $mailer
     * @param $retryTtl
     */
    public function __construct(
        BaseResettingController $resettingController,
        EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher,
        FactoryInterface $formFactory,
        UserManagerInterface $userManager,
        TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator,
        MailerInterface $mailer,
        $retryTtl,
        CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager
    )
    {
        $this->resettingController = $resettingController;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->retryTtl = $retryTtl;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function requestAction()
    {
        return $this->resettingController->requestAction();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function sendEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->resettingController->sendEmailAction($request);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function checkEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->resettingController->checkEmailAction($request);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $token
     * @return null|RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function resetAction(Request $request, string $token)
    {
        // custom reset action
    }
}
```

Comment: You make my day! Btw. one small error , in service you need to add - '@security.csrf.token_manager' after retry_ttl

Answer (score 4):

Follow the official documentation here : https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/override.html#controllers

To override, I find the documentation too ambigus, you have to add in your routing configuration, **BEFORE** FOS routing declaration, a route with the **same path** but **NOT the same route ID** :

```
fos_user_security_login_override:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: SecurityAppBundle:Security:login }

#FOS routing declaration comes AFTER
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Comment: This is the piece of info I was missing, works like a charm in symfony4.3!

Answer (score 0):

use of this role((only name of your controller without Bundle

```
{{ render(controller('@FOSUser/Registration/register')) }}
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand :/ When I copy your code, I have the error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Controller not found: service "@FOSUser/Registration/register" does not exist.").

Comment: Hey! I had a problem like you.I do it and fixed .I thought perhaps your problem will also be solved with this method